# Why do my model visualization and model estimates not match (R, ggplot)?

Tags: r, regression, interaction, ggplot2, regression-discontinuity

I am studying the relationship between government fiscal balances (BAL) and bond yields (LTINT). I have a simple regression discontinuity model with a numerical variable (BAL), a dummy (SGP: breach/compliant) and dummy interaction variable (SGP*BAL) investigating additional yield penalties when the fiscal balance is at -3 percent of GDP lower (breach).

```
model1D <- lm(LTINT ~ BAL + SGP + SGP*BAL, data3)
```

With output:

```
Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       -0.1898     0.7726  -0.246  0.80635    
BAL               -0.8505     0.1192  -7.137 9.79e-11 ***
SGPcompliant       1.4653     0.8284   1.769  0.07962 .  
BAL:SGPcompliant   0.6281     0.2150   2.922  0.00421 **
```

I have made a visualization of this model using ggplot and color = SGP:

```
  yieldplot1 <- ggplot(data3, aes(x = BAL, y = LTINT, color = SGP)) +
  geom_point(alpha = .8) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE, size = 1.25)
```

However, while the plot seems to show a negative value for the dummy variable estimate(trendline to the right of -3 is positioned lower than the one on the left), the model estimates say otherwise: balances to the right -3 attract a yield increase. Why is this? Have I made a mistake in assuming that by using color = SGP (dummy) the graph represents a model with dummy and interaction dummy?[image: yieldplot1]

Comment: It might be helpful to extract the predicted values from the model, order them by the *x* variable and plot them, maybe connected by a line, over your observed data.  This will give you an indication of what *y* values the model is predicting.

Comment: It's perhaps unfortunate that the standard summary of regression models is a display of model coefficient values, as when there are interactions those individual coefficients are very hard to interpret and can lead to this type of confusion. When there are interactions you have to go through the detailed calculations suggested by @SalMangiafico and illustrated in the answer from COOLSerdash, calculations that incorporate all the coefficients. This is a common source of confusion, gauged by the number of similar questions showing up on this site.

Comment: Just to be clear, *lm()* includes the predicted values in the output (hidden, but can be extracted).  So no hard work required for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**They do match.** Assuming that $\texttt{SGPcompliant}$ is $0$ for "breach" and $1$ for "compliant", the model based equations for the red line is: $\widehat{\texttt{LTINT}}= -0.1898 - 0.8505\cdot\text{BAL}$. For the green line, the estimated equation is: $\widehat{\texttt{LTINT}}=(-0.1898 + 1.4653) + (-0.8505 + 0.6281)\cdot\text{BAL}$ or $\widehat{\texttt{LTINT}}=1.2755 - 0.2224\cdot\text{BAL}$.

The coefficients would be interpreted as follows:

- $\beta_0 = -0.1898$ is the intercept of the line when $\texttt{SGPcompliant}$ is $0$, because the term $\beta_2\cdot\texttt{SGPcompliant}$ is $0$.
- $\beta_1 = -0.8505$ is the slope of the line when $\texttt{SGPcompliant}$ is $0$, because the interaction term $\beta_3\cdot\texttt{BAL:SGPcompliant}$ is $0$.
- $\beta_2 = 1.4653$ is *difference* between the intercept of the line when $\texttt{SGPcompliant}$ is $0$ and the intercept of the line when $\texttt{SGPcompliant}$ is $1$. So the intercept in that case is $-0.1898 + 1.4653 = 1.2755$.
- $\beta_3 = 0.6281$ is *difference* between the slope of the line when $\texttt{SGPcompliant}$ is $0$ and the slope of the line when $\texttt{SGPcompliant}$ is $1$. So the slope in that case is $-0.8505 + 0.6281 = -0.2224$.